# How to find a specific number in rows of lists using polynomial complexity with Python

Tags: python

I want to use a search algorithm with O(n^2) time complexity, to find the number 8 in the list [ [1, 2], [3, 5], [7, 8] ]

```
list1 = [[1,2],[3,5],[7,8]]
i=int(input('Number: '))
    for row in list1:
        for i in row:
           if i in list1:
              print('Exists')
           else:
              print('Does not exist')
```

Comment: What have you try?

Comment: question = [[1,2],[3,5],[7,8]]
def find_8 (question):
    i=8
    for row in question:
        for i in row:
            if i in question:
                print('Exists')
            else:
                print('Does not exist')

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to keep the formatting on here?

Comment: Don't reply, edit the question with your code. Also, itertools.chain.from_iterable

Comment: What is question_2? You aren't comparing the right things. You reused a variable name overwriting the old value. I'd suggest using better names so you know what they represent.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that you are re-defining the variable `i` when you create the for-loop. You are also, unnecessarily, looping over each of the numbers in each row. I would suggest changing the code to:

```
list1 = [[1,2],[3,5],[7,8]]
target = int(input('Number: '))

for row in list1:
    if target in row:
        print('Exists')
    else:
        print('Does not exist')
```

This will print `Exists` on the row which contains the number. Now if you want to actually find the coordinates of the target. Then I would suggest something like:

```py
list1 = [[1,2],[3,5],[7,8]]
target = int(input('Number: '))

for r, row in enumerate(list1):
    found = False

    for c, num in enumerate(row):
        if num == target:
            print(r, c)
            found = True
            break

    if found:
        break
```